# Detect memory pressure in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, memory

I have a WebGL application that can/may use a lot of memory.
I can reduce the memory (degrading the experience), but I'd rather do so only when necessary.

I'm having the most trouble with Firefox.
Is there a way in Firefox to:

1. Procedurally detect how much memory is available to my page's tab?
2. Receive something akin to iOS's didReceiveMemoryWarning notification?